# Rspec & Capybara test pass isolated, fail running together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I run the JS feature tests in isolation they work fine.

When I run the test suite, then they fail.

I execute '--bisect' with 'rspec spec' and return 1 test that produce the fail.

spec:
https://gist.github.com/lfgdz/c56481ce88cdb80750fa6d98f0ec1a4d

spec_helper:
https://gist.github.com/lfgdz/08b1b82d2a36aaf7929af79b04c652c1

Comment: Which specific spec fails? What happens when it fails? Please include enough information for the question to stand on its own.

Comment: You'r using a relational database too? I see nothing like databasecleaner for cleaning up after test.

Comment: **fails in the line 25:**
expect(page).to have_content('You need re-connect with LinkedIn from your Edit Profile page')

Comment: **says:**
1) Token expiration notifications After success login with expired authentication token at dashboard
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('You need re-connect with LinkedIn from your Edit Profile page')
       expected to find text "You need re-connect with LinkedIn from your Edit Profile page" in "Put your network to work for you LOG IN CONTACT US × × LOG IN Remember me Forgot your password?"

Comment: I'm using relational database: postgres, yes :)

Answer (score 2):

When specs pass in isolation but fail when run together, there must be some interdependency or information that's leaking between them.

As @slowjack2k said, your `spec_helper.rb` specifies:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Per the [RSpec Transactions](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions) doc, that means you've asked RSpec not to wrap each spec in a transaction. This means changes to the database made during one spec can impact others, including between standard unit tests and Capybara feature tests.

If you really need transaction fixtures turned off, you'll need to use [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) or some other mechanism to ensure that changes made in one spec don't interfere with other specs.